# How to use ASP.NET replace command to insert variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, replace, query-string

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TESTBOX" runat="server">SOME TEXT Query=0 MORE TEXT</asp:TextBox>

Protected Sub btnReplace_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim QueryID As String
    QueryID = Request.QueryString("Query")
    Dim MyText As String = Me.TESTBOX.Text      
    Dim MyTextNew = MyText.Replace("Query=0", "Query=" & QueryID)
    TESTBOX.Text = MyTextNew
End Sub
```

**QUESTION**
How do you replace text with a variable in ASP.NET VB?

Comment: Please define `don't work` here. Doesn't replace? Replace wrong? Get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Replacing text with a variable" works.

Try this:

```
Dim myVar As Integer = 12
Dim MyTextNew = MyText.Replace("Query=0", "Query=" & myVar)
```

and it should work.

The problem in your code is that your request for the QueryString doesn't return a value. Check it with the stack trace or msgbox() and notice that it is null.

Comment: Thanks Arman you are correct. The issue was with the requesting of my querystring from the page and not the code above. I should have tried inserting in manually as you suggested sooner.